# How to set encoding for gulp-javac?

Tags: java, gulp

I cannot find any doc about setting encoding (e.g: utf-8) for `gulp-javac`. I've tried setting `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and run `javac command manually` with success, but it failed on `gulp-javac`, which obviously does not understand this option. Any help would be appreciated.